Basic usage of secret manager in VB.net
I have the following two questions:
ONE
A long time ago I used to be able to see constants in the executable by simply opening the binary file it in a text editor. Is this still possible? In other words for application types such as a class library DLL or basic windows form executable is using secret manager necessary to keep parameters from being exposed?
TWO
All tutorials on implementing secrets that I found were very difficult to understand for a beginner, but I so far have
Private Function getTwilioParam(paramName As String) As String
    Dim result As String = "getTwilioParam Failed"
    Dim builder As New ConfigurationBuilder()
    builder.AddUserSecrets(Of TypeOf(Startup.GetTypeInfo().Assembly)) ()  ' I can't tell what to put in for "ProjectType"
    Dim configuration As IConfigurationRoot = builder.Build()

    '' Access secrets
    If paramName = "acctSID" Then result = configuration("Twilio:acctSID")
    If paramName = "authToken" Then result = configuration("Twilio:authToken")

    Return result
End Function

I cannot figure out what the arguments to .AddUserSecrets should be, for a .net class library (dll) or a stand-alone executable.
Any hints will be appreciated.

Generally speaking, if a user has any kind of (even read-only) access to the program executable then software cannot keep secrets; you can only try to obfsucate things - or use something like on-device protected storage. Consequently, it is impossible (and irresponsible) to ever use hardcoded secrets, even if they're encrypted or obfuscated within the program (because the program will need to decrypt them).

The situation is much worse in the .NET world than it was previously, because .NET assemblies are generally in IL which is more straightforward to decompile than native code.  Often, I can not only find any strings you are keeping, but even find out what you named them (if you haven't run your assembly through an obfuscator).  At a basic level is ildasm, at an advanced level is ILSpy (which is integrated into VS 2022 now).

Thank you all for taking valuable time for answering. So what is the use of the so called "Manage User secrets" in VS? is it just to hide it from co-developers ? Also, besides fixed parameters which are hopeless to hide, is there an option for preventing easy decoding of a proprietary algorithm or formula?


A long time ago I used to be able to see constants in the executable by simply opening the binary file it in a text editor. Is this still possible?

Yes, though a simple text editor will likely be tripped-up by non-ASCII-compatible encoding schemes - not that you should consider that any kind of protection or obfuscation, because it isn't: tools like IDA Pro, Ghidra, and WinDbg are freely available, extremely powerful, and with many knowledgable users; for this reason not even Microsoft bothers to obfuscate their executables.

In other words for application types such as a class library DLL or basic windows form executable is using secret manager necessary to keep parameters from being exposed?

The hard-and-fast rule is that you must not embed or hard-code any kind of secret, password, key, token, or anything of the kind in your program - even if it is stored in any encrypted form, and no matter how strong you think your obfuscation is.
Instead, your software should prompt the user to input the key/password/secret during its setup or configuration stage, and you should be distributing those secrets in a side-channel (such as an email or online portal) where users can copy-and-paste them from. Your software should then use a system-provided protected-storage system for storing those secrets at-rest (such as Windows DPAPI or .NET's ProtectedData APIs). Doing this means you can also associate secrets with your individual users which might be advantageous for you as it disincentivizes them to leak or release them - and in any event it helps protect those secrets from malicious attackers who might compromise your users' accounts/security/etc;
But keep in mind that provided your users run your software on their machines then you cannot keep secrets from your own users, this is why DRM is always doomed to be cracked eventually.

Thanks Dai. The take-away answer seems to be, forget about the whole "User-secrets" under all circumstances except in team development where you don't trust your team-members. If this is wrong, then please comment

@Ernesto I don't know what you mean by "user secrets"; but my overall point is that secrets/values/passwords should never be stored in your program binaries, instead they should be stored by the OS - I'm not saying "don't have secrets". As for "not trusting your team-members"... *blinks* ...that's absurd...  what's the context? (Also, note that I'm using the term "secret" in a strict technical sense; I'm starting to think you're using a different definition)

An example of a secret in the current program I'm writing is a subscription service password to send text messages. Since this password should not be included in the code since the so-called user-secrets facility will not protect it from being copied from the executable. That only leaves using user-secrets while the source-code is being written, where the said password is otherwise visible to those who have access to the source code/project. If this is not correct, then I can't think of any other possibilities where "user-secrests" applies.
